# Changing colors and removing margins using Bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 for a dynamic tabbed display. However, I'd like the content to have a different background color for each tab.

How can I do this?

Furthermore, I'd like to have that background color connect seamlessly to the tab itself. However, using this example from W3schools:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a margin that I can't seem to control between the tabs themselves and the padding, as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/kjv2ytgj/3.

How do I remove that?

My original solution was to have a "pane" style that gives a general background color to the grid-block containing the tabs, but then I can't figure out how to have dynamic tab content background colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent `margin` of the `.tab-content` comes from the fact it has a `padding-top` value smaller than the `margin-top` value of its first element, and the first element has `display:inline` (it's a `<h3>`).

To fix it, apply a `padding-top` value to `.tab-content` or `.tab-pane`, bigger than (or equal to) the `margin-top` of the first element in the `.tab-pane`, or change the display property of the `<h3>` to a block level value.

---

The second issue, changing colors of bootstrap tabs in various states, is a more intricate and delicate job. You need to pay close attention to details and have a deep understanding of CSS specificity, including `:hover` and `:focus` and `:active` states.

Unless you get your kicks out of solving CSS challenges with difficulty level set to  *"evil"*, you're better off using a Bootstrap theme or online theme creator for Bootstrap rather than writing the selectors yourself. What I personally do when I need this: I get the code from a Bootstrap theme and only change the colors, not touching the selectors.

As a last step, I added classes to the tabs and tab-panes which I want to have a different color (`.orange` and `.red` in the example below) and wrote some stronger selectors for the `background-color` property to override the previous set values:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #666;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
}
.tab-content .tab-pane {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}

/* the rest if overriding theme background-color for colored tabs */

.nav-justified > li > a.orange,
.nav-justified > li.active > a.orange,
.nav-justified > li.active > a.orange:hover,
.tab-pane.orange {
  background-color: #f50
}
.nav-justified > li > a.orange:hover {
  background-color: #d52;
}

.nav-justified > li > a.red,
.nav-justified > li.active > a.red,
.nav-justified > li.active > a.red:hover,
.tab-pane.red {
  background-color: #f00
}
.nav-justified > li > a.red:hover {
  background-color: #d00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 pane">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"><img src="img/img1.png" height=75 alt="logo1"><br>My header text 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" class="orange"><img src="img/img2.png" height=75 alt="logo2"><br>My header text 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" class="red"><img src="img/img3.png" height=75 alt="logo3"><br>My header text 3</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>HOME</h3>
          <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade orange">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade red">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```